# Nested MySQL query for multiple privacy check

Tags: php, mysql

I have 1 table post with `userid`, `posttypeid`, `privacy` and `originalpostid`

> Privacy can be 1 (Everyone),2 (Friends),3 (Friends & Followers),4 (Only Me)

User can share any user post but people who visits their wall can see post according to privacy between `userid` of original post and `currentuser`

I also have function which returns relation between `user` and `user2` but in this case with mysql single query how can I handle conditionally.

For example query returning 10 result and 4 of them are shared post now I've to check each post that if user privacy is 1 then it should be visible to all if 2 then visible to originalpostowner friend only like that

I have figure out some condition like

```
IF(originalpostid!=0,(privacy=1,true,(privacy=2,(ORIGINAL_POST_QUERY & then check if SUBQUERY_TO_RETURN_IF_USER_IS_FRIEND_OR_NOT),(privacy=3,(ORIGINAL_POST_QUERY & then check if SUBQUERY_TO_RETURN_IF_USER_IS_FRIEND_OR_FOLLOWER),(privacy=4,(ORIGINAL_POST_QUERY & then check if CHECK_IF_CURRENTUSER_AND_ORIGINALPOSTID_USERID_IS_SAME),true)))),true)
```

This one is bit messy and also in this case I have to run subquery all times for originalpost details to compare user id is there any easy solution for it ?

Comment: I would suggest that each time, a user visits a site from a user, you load then all the post which he should see, something in the style like:
SELECT posts WHERE privacy <= get_relation(user,visitor);

Comment: No, that's not the solution
in this case you take 2 variables user and visitor but in my case there's only visitor which can be available to me and user I've to take from each result and get userid from originalpostid record

Comment: What does your get_relation function return ? maybe something like this ?
 SELECT p.posts FROM users u, posts p. WHERE p.privacy - get_relations(visitorId, (Select userid from users where userId = p.orginalpostId)) <= 1;

Comment: it returns status between 2 users like if you and me are friends then it will return 1,2 if we are unknown then 1 if you are follower & friend both then 1,2,3 and if its myself then 1,2,3,4

Comment: I am sorry if I get something wrong, but if the function return these values, my above comment should be possible with a MAX(). (Of course it's not actuall code but the principe of privacy - MAX(get_relations(visitorId, (SELECT userId WITH orginalpostid )) <= 0 ??

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, a query like this would do it:-

```
SELECT Post.PostID 
FROM Post 
WHERE Post.StatusID=2 
AND Post.privacy = 1
UNION
SELECT Post.PostID 
FROM Post 
INNER JOIN relationship
ON Post.userid = relationship.userid
WHERE Post.StatusID=2 
AND relationship.status = 2
AND relationship.userid_other = $CurrentUser
AND Post.privacy = 2
UNION 
SELECT Post.PostID 
FROM Post 
INNER JOIN relationship
ON Post.userid = relationship.userid
WHERE Post.StatusID=2 
AND relationship.status = 1
AND relationship.userid_other = $CurrentUser
AND Post.privacy = 3
UNION 
SELECT Post.PostID 
FROM Post 
WHERE Post.StatusID=2 
AND Post.userid = $CurrentUser
```

assuming a table of relationships like this:-

```
CREATE TABLE relationship
(
    userid  INT,
    userid_other    INT,
    status  INT
);

status = 1 for follower, 2 for friend
```

This is 4 unioned queries (union will exclude duplicates). The query first gets posts which are for everyone, the 2nd posts that are for friends where the current user is a friend of the poster, the 3rd gets posts which are for followers where the current user is a follower of the poster and the 4th gets posts which are open for anyone to read.

But to give anything better I would need to know how your relationships are stored.

Comment: there're 2 different tables for friends and followers but yes your query can help me bit to create actual working query I mean I can get idea from it :)